# MAC write to desktop from shell script

Tags: macos, bash

Is there a way to display messages to the MAC desktop from a BASH script? I am writing a terminal window script, that needs to display a message on the MAC desktop. Also if the was a way to open a message box from a BASH script.

Dennis

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it will work.

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
osascript -e 'Tell application "System Events" to display dialog "Some Funky Message"'
```

[image]

Or, if you want the user to input something and get the result...

```
#!/bin/bash
input=$(osascript -e 'Tell application "System Events" to display dialog "Enter something:" default answer ""' -e 'text returned of result' 2>/dev/null)
echo $input
```

[image]

And, to anticipate your next question, if you want `bash` variables in the dialog box and also quotes and stuff, you can use this form of sending the script into `osascript` on its `stdin`:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=7
input=$(osascript <<EOF
Tell application "System Events" to display dialog "Steve's Funky Message ($var) with apostrophe and variable"
EOF)
```

[image]