# Create a MessageBox in Python for Mac?

Tags: python, macos, ctypes, messagebox

Currently working through a free online class for Python from Cybrary (I'm coding in 3.6), but I use a Mac while the presenter uses Windows. So far, there have been very few differences if any.

The current section deals with learning and using Ctypes however, and the "assignment" says to `Write a function which takes two arguments, title and body and creates a MessageBox with those arguments`.

The code used in the video as an example of creating a Message Box:

```
from ctypes import *

windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, "Click Yes or No\n", "This is a title\n", 4)
```

---

My code:

```
# 2.1 Ctypes: Write a function which takes two arguments, title and body
#  and creates a MessageBox with those arguments
def python_message_box(title, body):
    return windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, body, title, 0)
```

Running this gives the error:

```
File ".../AdvancedActivities.py", line 9, in python_message_box
   return windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, body, title, 0)
NameError: name 'windll' is not defined
```

I don't believe I need to say that I get the same error trying to run

```
windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, body, title, 0)
```

---

I haven't been able to find any examples anywhere of people creating Message Boxes on Mac computers. Is it a Windows-specific function? If so, what would be the Mac equivalent of this?

EDIT: Mark Setchell's solution is to have Python run terminal functions that accomplish `windll` tasks, so instead of `windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, body, title, 0)`, use:

```
command = "osascript -e 'Tell application \"System Events\" to
           display dialog \""+body+"\"'"
system(command)
```

Comment: Calling `windll.user32.MessageBoxA()` is most definitely Windows-specific. There are ways of doing the equivalent on almost _any_ system using the `tkinter` module.

Comment: I forgot to say, you can also do `.... display dialog "blah blah" with title "Put your title here"`

Comment: I know that this question is answered, but I wanted to tell you that I've made a simple package that does this: https://github.com/ninest/notipy_osx 
It is basically a wrapper around apple script

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you type this into a Terminal on any Mac, you'll get a dialog box:

```
osascript -e 'Tell application "System Events" to display dialog "Some Funky Message" with title "Hello Matey"'
```

[image]

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28749940/2836621) for further examples.

So, just use a Python subprocess call to run that... [subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), or use `system()`.

Nothing to install. No dependencies. You can also ask user for values, select files or directories and pick colours using the same technique. The dialog boxes are all native Mac ones - not some ugly imitation.

Comment: Ok that's pretty cool. Currently though, I have to run `system("osascript -e 'Tell application \"System Events\" to display dialog \""+body+"\"'")` to get it to work. `subprocess` is being funky.

Comment: Be careful with this - if an attacker can manipulate "Some Funky Message", they can run arbitrary code on your user's machine by adding quotes and then shell commands in the message.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

body_Str="Body of Dialog"

title_Str="Title"

os.system("""osascript -e \'Tell application \"System Events\" to display dialog \""+body_Str+"\" with title \""+title_Str+"\"\'""")
```

this is much better

Comment: Please, explain (even briefly) what you code does and how it answer the question. Have a look at [*How do I write a good answer?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Tried this in python 3.11 but it fails saying body_Str is not defined...   How to pass a python variable to osascript?