# error when running a python code on Mac OS

Tags: python

My son has just started learning python in school and he has to write a simple program on Mac OS.

the code is this

```
import ctypes


def mBox(mode, message, title, style):
    return(ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(mode, message, title, style))

MB_OK = 0
MB_OKCANCEL = 1
MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE = 2
MB_YESNOCXL = 3
MB_RETRYNO = 5
MB_CANCELTRYAGAINCONTINUE = 6
MB_HELP = 16384
ICON_EXCLAIM = 48
ICON_INFO = 64
ICON_STOP = 16

IDOK = 0
IDCANCEL = 2
IDABORT = 3
IDYES = 6
IDNO = 7


result = mBox(None, "Do you know what you are doing?","Support",ICON_EXCLAIM | MB_HELP)


if result == IDYES:
    print("user pressed Yes")
elif result == IDNO:
    print("user pressed No")
elif result == IDCANCEL:
    print("user pressed Cancel")
else:
    print("unknown return code",result)
```

When this code is executed the following message is displayed

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/KeeganBarretto/Documents/MESSAGE BOXES 5.py", line 25, in <module>
    result = mBox(None, "Do you know what you are doing?","Support",ICON_EXCLAIM | MB_HELP)
  File "/Users/KeeganBarretto/Documents/MESSAGE BOXES 5.py", line 5, in mBox
    return(ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(mode, message, title, style))
AttributeError: module 'ctypes' has no attribute 'windll'
```

Can someone help him in resolving this issue. As I mentioned he is new to python and learning as part of his computer studies.

Comment: `windll` is for Windows, not Unix.

Answer (score 2):

That code only works on Windows, since it's calling `MessageBoxW` from the Windows `user32.dll`.

Comment: is there any alternative ?

Comment: Replacing the message box call with a macOS alternative (quick search gives e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50497479/create-a-messagebox-in-python-for-mac), or running this on Windows.